# Can i catch browser popup cancel event in my angular code?

Tags: angular, events, browser, popup, cancel-button

In my condition, when I redirect the user to another page, the browser throws me this type of popup: "Changes that you made may not be saved."and it has two options: leave and cancel. If I click on leave, it will redirect me to another page, and if I click on cancel, it will pop up a cancel popup. I want to catch this popup cancel event and do some operations in my code in Angular.

I want to catch the popup calendar event and do some operations in Angular.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the popup?